# How do I make a Regex that captures book highlights from a file created in my Amazon Kindle?

Tags: regex

My Amazon Kindle contains a `.txt` file which it saves all my highligts to and I'm making a program that reads from the file and with regex break each highlight down, so I can save them to a database

I'm only interested in capturing every `Book Title`, `AuthorFirstName` and `AuthorLastName` and the `Some highlighted text from the kindle`

The following is a sample of highlights saved in `.txt`

```
==========
Book Title (AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName)
- Your Highlight on page 4 | location 45-46 | Added on Thursday, 19 March 2020 15:37:14

Some highlighted text from the kindle
==========
Book Title (AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName)
- Your Highlight on page 4 | location 45-46 | Added on Thursday, 19 March 2020 15:37:14

Some highlighted text from the kindle
==========
Book Title (AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName)
- Your Highlight on page 4 | location 45-46 | Added on Thursday, 19 March 2020 15:37:14

Some highlighted text from the kindle
==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code, I am using javascript here. Run it to see the output. And you can see the detailed explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/5LFBLN/1) of the regex used

```js
const regex = /^([a-z A-Z]*)\(([a-z A-Z]*)\)$|^\n(.*)\n=*$/gm;
const str = `==========
Rich Dad Poor Dad (Namar sood)
- Your Highlight on page 4 | location 45-46 | Added on Thursday, 19 March 2020 15:37:14

Rich dad poor dad book hihglight
==========
The Monk who sold his ferrari (Namar sood)
- Your Highlight on page 4 | location 45-46 | Added on Thursday, 19 March 2020 15:37:14

The Monk who sold his ferrari highlight
==========
two states (Namar sood)
- Your Highlight on page 4 | location 45-46 | Added on Thursday, 19 March 2020 15:37:14

two states highlight
==========`;

let matches = str.matchAll(regex);

let flag = true;
for (const match of matches) {
    if(flag){
        console.log("Title: ",match[1], "\nAuthor name: ", match[2]);
        flag = false;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Highlight: ",match[3], "\n-----------------\n");
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like you're already did something similar before. I think I can use it all of it and convert it to my needs